# Android USB Virtual COM port on an Archos?

Tags: android, serial-port, virtual, port, archos

is there any option to have Virtual COM port Host on Android that would communicate with a connected device(via cable and physical USB unterface) in a virtual COM port *way* (fileopen/fileread/filewrite/fileclose)?
I believe that kernel reconfiguring/recompiling is not possible

Comment: Which Archos product are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for doing that. We gave up and change software on a device from classical RS232 to HID and now it works.